# How to separate the searchBar and tableview in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, searchbar

I build the searchController and the tableview.

But I refer more web documents. There are always add the searchBar to tableview header.

like below:

```
 self.displayTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

But Now I don't want to add the searchBar to the tableHeaderView.

I try to add direct the view(searchBarBgVW  ). But the searchrBar was not show at screen.

as below:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
  ......
  .........
 // --- search bar declare ---

 self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

 //    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x,      self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y,      self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
 //    self.displayTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

 self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

 self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);    
 [self.searchBarBgVW addSubview: self.searchController.searchBar];

 self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
 self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
 .....
 ....
 ..
 }
```

If I open the comment about the tableheader like below:

```
 self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,      self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

     self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
     self.displayTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
     [self.view addSubview: self.searchController.searchBar];
```

The search bar will show at the place (0,0),

But the TableHeader will show white block.

[image]

How can I add the searchbar place using the searchController at correct method?Or How can I remove the tableviewheader white block?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: So bad,I was not found  the resolution about this. If you have find the resolution, please offer to me, thank you very much.

Comment: I have the search bar working as you did initially (part of tableview header). How have you defined you controller? UIViewController or UITableViewController? Are you creating a TableView as an addition to a UIViewController? Do you have a custom cell? Could you add a snapshot of your storyboard for this controller? Perhaps together we can solve this.

Comment: I am using uiviewcontroller. I just drag a tableview to uiviewcontroller. but I search web information usually put the search bar in the table header. I don't what put the search bar in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a (newish) [UICatalog sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/Swift_UICatalog_SearchPresentOverNavigationBarViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710-Swift_UICatalog_SearchPresentOverNavigationBarViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_75) that includes all kinds of search capabilities. It is divided into pretty simple controllers.. It's provided in both Swift and ObjC.